# What would happen if non-cellular immune responses didn’t happen?

Tags: immune-system, immunology

First things first, I’m not from a medical background, so apologies for the slightly vague question and any other poor wording throughout.

I’ve recently caught a nasty cold, and as such I’ve acquired the standard set of symptoms - headache due to temperature, blocked nose, physical tiredness and poor mental faculties. I’ve called these “non-cellular” as (to me at least) they seem to be effects that occur on a larger scale - they affect me globally, as opposed to my immune cells which help me on a local cell level. From what I understand, they are largely caused by cytokines triggering responses in the brains. (Most of what I understand comes from some ted animated video.) the point is raised that it potentially helps mitigate the ability of bacteria to grow by various means.
So what I was wondering is with a relatively mild infection, could your body do fine without some/all of these “global” effects, i.e. would the immunecell vs infected cell battle be sufficient? Perhaps there are some cases where cytokines don’t function properly in some individuals?

Comment: Your question seems to be how does the immune system work.

Comment: No, my question is could the immune response without increased body temperature, decreased appetite etc., still be sufficient against mild infections, which I though i made quite clear but I can try to improve it? Or if this is still too vague I can try to make a new question?

Comment: You don't need a new question; you simply need to edit this one to clarify what you're asking. Your question as it is now boils down to "Can you survive without an innate immune system?" The answer to that is no, you'd be dead within days. But you seem to want to narrow it down to the parts of the innate immune response you notice, like fever. That's a purely speculative question that's not really within the realm of possibilities. Perhaps you could narrow it down to asking what the function of a fever is? And then you need to add some prior research on your part, which is a requirement here.